# Libcurl persistant connection "Connection #0 seems to be dead!"

Tags: http, curl, connection, libcurl

I need to establish persistent SSL connection to the server and get some informations back. I'd like to send requests with specified time intervals between them. Now I came across some problem with libcurl. Namely if I send one request one after the other, everything works just fine, however if there occurred some time interval between them, libcurl closes current connection with message "Connection #0 seems to be dead!" and establish another one, of course breaks the persistent connection.

My code bases on http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/persistant.html

I have no specification of the server I'm connecting to, but I've tested some ready application and it is able to do it properly using raw sockets.

My question is, is it because of libcurl or the server side?

Answer (score 0):

This message is shown when libcurl wants to re-use the connection but it has been closed in the mean time. As you mention there's been some time in between since it was used, that time is then probably longer than the idle timeout the server allows so the server has closed the connection since.

This should not cause a problem other than a slightly slower second request since libcurl needs to setup a connection again.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first request is about authorization and further ones just get some data provided we're already authorized. So whenever the persistent connection is lost we need to do it one more time which is undesirable.